# Custom date range (x-axis) in time series with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

My code to plot a time series is this:

```
def plot_series(x, y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(x, y, fmt='g--') # x = array of dates, y = array of numbers

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

I have a few thousand data points and so matplotlib creates x-axis range of 3 months. This is what my time series looks like right now:

[image]

However, I want a weekly/fortnightly series. How do I change the way matplotlib computes date ranges the x-axis, and since I have almost 1 year of data, how do I make sure all of it fits nicely in one single chart?

Comment: would something as simple as `ax.set_xlim([min_time, max_time])` work or do you need something more automatic?

Comment: That would limit the min and max value. What I want is much more "magnified" graph. So instead of 3 month intervals, I want 1 week or 2 weeks intervals.

Comment: Hmm. If I'm following you, you want to read your data into a pandas DataFrame, and then resample: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html#time-series

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the frequency of tickmarks on your x-axis, you have to set its locator.

To have tickmarks for every monday of every week, you can use the [`WeekdayLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator) provided by the [`dates`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates) module of matplotlib.

*(Untested code)*:

```
from matplotlib.dates import WeekdayLocator

def plot_series(x, y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(x, y, fmt='g--') # x = array of dates, y = array of numbers        

    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    # For tickmarks and ticklabels every week
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO))

    # For tickmarks and ticklabels every other week
    #ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=2))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

This may get a bit crowded on the x-axis when using only one plot, as this generates approximately 52 ticks.

One possible work-around to this is to have ticklabels for every *n*-th week (e.g. every 4th week), and only tickmarks (i.e. no ticklabels) for every week:

```
from matplotlib.dates import WeekdayLocator

def plot_series(x, y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot_date(x, y, fmt='g--') # x = array of dates, y = array of numbers        

    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    # For tickmarks and ticklabels every fourth week
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO, interval=4))

    # For tickmarks (no ticklabel) every week
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=MO))

    # Grid for both major and minor ticks
    plt.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Along with `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))`, this works like charm!